# Mapbox - console.warning = "The sun direction is attached to a light with viewport anchor, lighting may behave unexpectedly"

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

the mapbox docs talk about setting the light anchor to 'map', but where exactly do you do this? [Mapbox Docs setLight()](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/light/)

Answer (score 0):

To set the light anchor to map at run time, you would do:

```
map.setLight({ anchor: 'map' });
```